# array of array php order by 2 fields string and number

Tags: php, arrays, usort, array-multisort

i have a array which contains itsefl array  like s['name'] s['age']
I don't know exactly how represent the structure [ or },

```
tab {
       s { ['name']
            ['age']
         }
```

}

it my code there is
      function cmp($a, $b)
     {
      return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
     }

```
  usort($result, "cmp");

 foreach($result as $s) {
  foreach($s as $t) {
    DisplayError("antoine 20")
    DisplayError("antoine 88")
    DisplayError("antoine 19")
  }
```

}

I would like to sort first by name then age

I search a long time but difficult

Comment: I found a trick i have done a new array ['nameAge'] and i use       function cmpNameAge($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['nameAge'], $b['nameAge']); 
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use this comparator:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
        return $a['age'] - $b['age'];
    }
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');
```